# Custom back arrow in toolbar not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library, android-toolbar

After using a custom back arrow on my toolbar, it doesn't go back as it should when I press it. How can this issue be resolved?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String actionBarColor = "#FFD300";

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionBarColor)));
        actionBar.setElevation(0);

        Toolbar tBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_yellow);
        setSupportActionBar(tBar);

        tBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**toolbar_yellow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_yellow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FFD300"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_arrow_back">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_text"
        android:text="yellow"
        android:textColor="#000099"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="2"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: where is the customarrown back button in your code?

Comment: @MacaronLover just checkout my update answer i added to the code.

Comment: i posted a answer you can look at it

Comment: Your logic seems a little off. If `actionBar != null`, then `setSupportActionBar()` should be throwing an Exception. Are you sure it's even entering the `if` block? You need a `NoActionBar` theme, or similar, for your `Activity`.

Comment: @MacaronLover, I'm curious why you have a `TextView` in your `Toolbar`. If it's to set the `Toolbar` title, you can do this with the `setTitle(int)` or `setTitle(CharSequence)` methods in your activity without the need for the `TextView`.

Comment: @iRuth How can I make the title multine programmatically (maximum 2 lines)?

Comment: @MacaronLover, if that's what you're trying to accomplish, what you have done will work if your text extends to multiple lines.

Comment: I know, but it would be better if this could be done programmatically only. Also the back button STILL doesn't work.

Comment: @MacaronLover, check my answer and let me know if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this line

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

UpDate :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String actionBarColor = "#FFD300";

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionBarColor)));
        actionBar.setElevation(0);

        Toolbar tBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_yellow);
        setSupportActionBar(tBar);

       getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_arrow_back);

        tBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this will certainly display the `Up` (it's not actually called the `Back` arrow).

Comment: That still doesn't make a difference i'm using a custom drawable for the back arrow not the android one.

Comment: @MacaronLover see my Update answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code to what's below. Since you're setting the `Toolbar` color in the `toolbar_yellow.xml` layout file, you don't need to set it in code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar tBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_yellow);

    setSupportActionBar(tBar);
    tBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't have any custom back button, even you can display it by setting a line in manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

for displaying custom icon

```
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
```

and handling it as

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know but I DO have a custom one!